# Overriding Manifest config on Gradle build using Robolectric 3.0

Tags: gradle, robolectric

## Background

Robolectric [claim to support overriding application manifest](http://robolectric.org/configuring/):

```
@Config(manifest = "some/build/path/AndroidManifest.xml")
public class SandwichTest {

    @Config(manifest = "other/build/path/AndroidManifest.xml")
    public void getSandwich_shouldReturnHamSandwich() {
    }
}
```

But it seems that on Gradle, [this feature is broken](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2539).

## My question

How can one override the manifest while building on Gradle using Robolectric 3.0?

Comment: As a workaround, you can create two test classes with different `config` section

Comment: Thanks @EugenMartynov but not event `some/build/path/AndroidManifest.xml` works. Is there any way to tell Robolectric to use any non-default AndroidManifest?

Comment: What is the error message? Perhaps your manifest path is incorrect. Try with and without module folder in your path.